# Inequality in Evans PDE section 5.7

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I'm stuck in the proof of the Compactness Theorem in Evans PDE 2nd edition book. On page 287, last line, how do you get the inequality $$ \epsilon \int_{B\left(0,1\right)}\eta\left(y\right)\int^{1}_{0}\int_{V}\left|Du_{m}\left(x-\epsilon ty\right)\right|dxdtdy \leq \epsilon\int_{V}\left|Du_{m}\left(z\right)\right|dz.$$
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The function $|Du_m|$ is compactly supported in $V$, and moreover it is assumed that its support is at distance more than $\epsilon$ from the boundary of $V$. Therefore, for every $t\in [0,1]$ and $y\in B(0,1)$ integration of $|Du_m(x-\epsilon ty)|$ over $V$ gives the same result as integration of $|Du_m(x)|$. (Translating the function by less than $\epsilon$ within the domain does not change the integral.) Thus,

$$\begin{split}
\int_{B\left(0,1\right)}\eta\left(y\right)\int^{1}_{0}\int_{V}\left|Du_{m}\left(x-\epsilon ty\right)\right|dxdtdy 
&= \int_{B\left(0,1\right)}\eta\left(y\right)\int^{1}_{0}\int_{V}\left|Du_{m}\left(x \right)\right|dxdtdy \\ 
&= \int_{V}\left|Du_{m}\left(x \right)\right|dx \int_{B\left(0,1\right)}\eta\left(y\right)\,dy\int^{1}_{0}dt \\ 
&= \int_{V}\left|Du_{m}\left(x \right)\right|dx   \\ 
\end{split} $$